# When Is the Squeeze(Sandwich) Theorem Used?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am beginning to learn Calculus 1, and I was taught about the squeeze (sandwich) theorem. It seems to me that all the problems given have $\sin$ involved. Is this true? When is the squeeze theorem applied?

Also, what are the standard "squeeze functions"? For example, I know that $-1\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$ and this is used in a $\sin$-involved problem. Are there other such functions to apply when using the squeeze theorem?

Comment: This might be a bit of a stretch, but wikipedia provides a [nice example in multivarible calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Fourth_example).

Comment: The squeeze theorem is helpful whenever we suspect that a limit might exist at a point, but don't want to do a tedious limit calculation or proof. It tells us that it suffices to bound the function above and below by functions that share a limit at that point. The upshot of this is that we can usually pick the bounding functions to have known or more easily calculable limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not necessary that sine functions are involved in all Sandwich Theorem Problems.

1. Sandwich Theorem is commonly used in computing Integrals as a limit of a sum.
2. It is used in Limit Computations
3. It is used in proving convergence of many series by bounding it.
4. I found another interesting use with many applications in itself. The limit of the sinc function can be proved using the theorem which provides a first order approximation that is used in Physics. This function also shows up as the fourier transform of a rectangular wave.
   You can read more about this specific function in the top answer (answered anonymously) to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-real-life-applications-of-the-Squeeze-Theorem) Quora question.

Examples of functions where squeeze theorem can be applied-

Limit of the function-

$f(x)=x^2 e^{\sin\frac{1}{x}}$

As x approaches 0

The limit is not normally defined because the function oscillates infinitely many times as it approaches zero

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your post, but the squeeze theorem doesn't let us assign limits to functions that don't "normally" have limits. On the contrary, it gives us a criterion for determining when the limit of a function exists.

Comment: @charleshudges what I meant to say is that it gives us bounds for the upper and lower value which turn up to be equal and is the limit for the function at that point

Comment: I would still argue that this is running the theorem in reverse. To be precise, the squeeze theorem says that if there exist $f, h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} h(x) = L$ and $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \in X$, then $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = L$. It doesn't give us the functions. We supply functions which have the above properties and conclude that the limit exists (and is equal to $L$).

Comment: @charleshudges seems like I wasn't able to make my point properly. I never mention that it gives us functions it indeed is used in the functions which have the property which you mentioned. Maybe I'm not getting the mistake I'm making can you be more specific about which point you're talking about and how you would suggest i modify it

Comment: I think I misread your comment. Were you saying that when we have $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = K$ and $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x$, then if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M$ exists, then $L \leq M \leq K$? If so, that is true, but it isn't the result that is usually called the squeeze theorem. Note that in this case we have to suppose $g$ has a limit to say anything useful. By contrast, the squeeze theorem is precisely the statement that the limit of $g$ exists at $a$ when $L = K$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins i meant the former which you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The squeeze theorem provides an intuitive rule for making statements about the convergence of a given series when it is bounded above and below ("squeezed") by 2 other series which are known to converge.

That you are seeing a lot of examples that use trig functions is purely coincidental. What is even more likely is that most of the examples you see also involve *quotients*, since the squeeze theorem is often used to prove the existence of a limit where the denominator of a function is zero. But agin, it is a general rule and is not restricted to any particular class of function.

Comment: Are there any generalities about the squeeze function?

Comment: It's not a generalization, but to clarify a little: squeeze theorem doesn't just state *that* a limit exists, but it also says what that limit is: if `A` is bounded above by `B` and below by `C`, and at point `x` both `B` and `C` converge to `y`, then `A` also converges to `y` at point `x`.

Answer (score 1):

[Squeeze Theorem](https://mathculus.com/what-is-the-squeeze-theorem-sandwich-theorem/) is used to find the limit of a function when other methods are failed to do that.

Now see this example: Show that $\lim _{t \to 2}g(t)=-1$ when $-\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+t^{2}-\frac{7}{3} \leq g\left ( t \right ) \leq \cos \left ( \frac{t \pi}{2} \right )$.

This is an example of the Squeeze theorem not involving sine function.

We can evaluate the limit using the squeeze theorem.

Solution:

Given that $-\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+t^{2}-\frac{7}{3} \leq g\left ( t \right ) \leq \cos \left ( \frac{t \pi}{2} \right )$

Now $\lim _{t \to 2}\left ( -\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+t^{2}-\frac{7}{3} \right )$

= $\lim _{t \to 2} -\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+ \lim_ {t _\to 2}t^{2}- \lim _{t _\to 2}\frac{7}{3}$

=$-\frac{1}{3}(2)^{3}+ (2)^{2}-\frac{7}{3}$

=$-\frac{8}{3}+ 4-\frac{7}{3}$

=$\frac{-8+12-7}{3}$

=$\frac{-3}{3}$

= $-1$

and $ \lim _{t \to 2} \cos \left ( \frac{t \pi}{2} \right ) = \cos \left ( \frac{2 \pi}{2} \right ) = \cos \pi = -1$

Since $-\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+t^{2}-\frac{7}{3} \leq g\left ( t \right ) \leq \cos \left ( \frac{t \pi}{2} \right )$ and $\lim _{t \to 2}\left (-\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+t^{2}-\frac{7}{3} \right )=-1=\cos \left ( \frac{t \pi}{2} \right )$

Therefore by Squeeze Theorem,

$$\lim _{t \to 2}g(t)=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

A nice example for an application of the squeeze theorem which does not involve any trigonometric functions: Show that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x \cdot \lfloor 1/x\rfloor =1$$

(where $\lfloor \rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).)